# Daz3d to blender? Model has white eyes!

Tags: modeling, texturing

I don't know if this is the place to ask this question, but currently I am making a Daz model. I imported her to blender and she has white eyes. I keep finding tutorials on how to fix it but their basically like, "Step 1: Just do it." I don't **know** how to do it though. The only thing I could think of is that I few of the eye properties don't have the textures with them. Since this is the case what do I do?

*Cornea, tear, and eye reflection are missing the texture beside them

[image: Cornea, tear, and eye reflection are missing the texture beside them]

1. Thank you do much to anyone who can even slightly help.
2. If this is not the place to ask this sort of question where would I ask it?
3. If you know how to fix this please give step by step written/video/picture instructions that are detailed! (for example: Just fix the eye surface to transparent bsdf) **I don't know where that even is!**

edit: Only the eyes of the model are white. I thought there should be an eye surface texture but I don't see it.

Here is the blend file --- file:///C:/Users/Sequoia/AppData/Local/Temp/x1.blend

Comment: What format was used for importing ? Probably "EyeReflection" and "Tear" shouldn't have textures because they reflect light but don't have thir own color. Can you show setup of the Cornea material ? How many textures does model have iin Daz (i.e. how many of them should be in Blender) ? Are other parts of the model white as well ? Or are the eyes the only ones ? This is quite narrow problem so [edit] question to add screenshots and if you can [a blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). If there are too many links add them in comments to your question.

Comment: I sent the blend file over, I am not quite sure what else to do, hopefully you can go in and investigate what is happening.If the model is purple make sure blender is on blender render not cycles at the top. And make sure you click the ball next to object mode and set it to textured. That should be it thanks again! @Mr

Comment: Please [upload the blend file with this link](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so it becomes accessible to others because it isn't while is located on your local hard drive. Also it would useful if you edit the question not only with file but with some screenhosts as well like material node setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imported a Genesis2 model from DAZ studio to Blender (2.7) using .dae format, and encountered this too. 
Some parts of the eye need to be textured (e.g. iris, pupils and sclera) as you would expect, but the cornea (The outer jelly-like part) must obviously be transparent just like a real eye. The material it has by default makes it white which is what you encountered.

So - select the eye objects (LEye and REye) in the Object tree (usually top right of the screen)
In the materials properties for that object you should see a list of pre-assigned materials.
For both 'Cornea' and 'Eye Reflection' assign a new Glass material since they must be transparent so you can see the rest of the eye. 
For that glass material I would change the IOR to about 1.1 so that it's really transparent.
Not sure if this is the right approach but it worked for me :)

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to just type thank you, but I felt like you should really know! You're one of the only people who really helped @Justin Leppan

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem whilst using the daz bridge and trying to import several Genesis 2 characters into blender. I found the following tutorial which shows exactly how to get rid of the white eye issue with the latest version of Blender (2.9) and includes pictures for non technical users:

https://pixelsizzle.com/how-to-use-the-daz-to-blender-bridge/

The basic process described is to use the Daz to Blender bridge to import your character.  Then to replace the Eye Reflection surface with a Transparent shader.

Hope this helps folks out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with DAZ, but there is a similar issue with exports from Makehuman.

The eyes render properly but are white in the view-port.  This is due to the eyes having a transparent layer over the visible eye texture and the Blender 3D view-port doesn't support transparencies.

This isn't a serious problem as long as it renders properly, but it is admittedly irritating when trying to pose them.