# POSER - Can Poser files be used in Blender and Blender in Poser?

Tags: import

I only know Poser (now by Smith Micro) and use it for 3D stills.  Poser human characters/figures (with wireframes made by SmithMicro, DAZ3D or HiveWire) with photo-human textures can be extremely realistic, better than any other 3D programs I've seen.  I wish I could try my Poser figures in Blender to try its renderer, lighting, clothing creation, landscape creation, etc. 
I don't yet know Blender; do any of you use Poser and Blender??
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Daz studio uses poser models and according to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79537/935) exporting the model using collada (.dae) works, .fbx may also be a good option. You could export a posed character with .obj but that doesn't include the armature.

While each renderer can use the same image textures, expect some manual texture creating to use cycles, which is blender's newer and better render engine. You will probably find this much easier with the new principled shader in the new blender version about to be released. You can test it in the [daily builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/) and see it in use in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck)

I would suggest asking/looking at poser specific sites like the [daz3d forums](https://www.daz3d.com/forums/) which is where I first heard about blender years ago, people using it to make poser models.